# How to refer to a range of items on a list on python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a program that generates lists

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]
list3 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, o, p]
```

how can i write a piece of code that extracts all the items from a given index  all the way to the end and assigns them to a new variable?

For example, if I want to get all the items from index 3 to the end of the list of list3 and assign them to list4

```
list4 = [d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, o, p]
```

I am repeating myself when I say 'to the end' beacuse I need something that works for all the lists that variy in ranges.

Comment: Are list1 and list2 even relevant for this? If so, how?

Comment: `list4 = list3[3:]`

Comment: I just put list1 and 2 (that are both different lengths) to clarify that if I only had one list I could just put the range of the list (from index 3 to index whatever) but i needed a method that worked on the three of them no matter the length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple:

```
list4 = list3[3:]
```